# Java .. Given public class and no Main method as part of a group project .. how do I compile?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, methods, program-entry-point

Taking an online intro Java class and my unresponsive professor provided us "public class Airline" to correct errors, make more efficient, add features, etc.  Only the .txt file was provided.  So far in class I have originated all my own code in Eclipse.  How do I take a supplied .txt file with no main method and try to compile it so I can work on the assignment?

Thanks for any input.
Mike

'''

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Airline
{

    boolean seats[]; // array of seats
    final int SIZE = 10;  // number of seats
    final int FIRST_CLASS = 1;
    final int ECONOMY_CLASS = 2;

   public Airline()
   {
      seats = new boolean[ SIZE ]; // array of seats
   }

   // prints boarding pass
   public void printBoardingPass( int seat )
   {
      String section = ( seat < 5 ) ? "First Class" : "Economy Class";
      System.out.printf( "%s. Seat #%d\n", section, seat );
   }

   // print seating menu
   public void printMenu()
   {
      System.out.println( "Please type 1 for First Class" );
      System.out.println( "Please type 2 for Economy" );
      System.out.print( "choice: " );
   }

   // checks customers in and assigns them a boarding pass
   public void checkIn()
   {      
      int firstClass = 0; // next available first class seat
      int economy = 5; // next available economy seat      
      int section = 0; // passenger's seating choice

      Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

      System.out.println( "Welcome to Java Airways" );

      while ( ( firstClass < 5 ) || ( economy < 10 ) )
      {
         printMenu();
         section = input.nextInt();

         if ( section == FIRST_CLASS ) // user chose first class
         {
            if ( firstClass < 5 )
            {
               seats[ firstClass++ ] = true;
               printBoardingPass( firstClass );
            } // end if 
            else if ( economy < 10 ) // first class is full
            {
               System.out.println(
                  "First Class is full, Economy Class?" );
               System.out.print( "1. Yes, 2. No. Your choice: " );
               int choice = input.nextInt();

               if ( choice == 1 )
               {
                  seats[ economy++ ] = true;
                  printBoardingPass( economy );
               }
               else
                  System.out.println( "Next flight leaves in 3 hours." );
            } // end else if
         } // end if
         else if ( section == ECONOMY_CLASS ) // user chose economy
         {
            if ( economy < 10 ) 
            {
               seats[ economy++ ] = true;
               printBoardingPass( economy );
            } // end if 
            else if ( firstClass < 5 ) // economy class is full
            {
               System.out.println(
                  "Economy Class is full, First Class?" );
               System.out.print( "1. Yes, 2. No. Your choice: " );
               int choice = input.nextInt();

               if ( choice == 1 )
               {
                  seats[ firstClass++ ] = true;
                  printBoardingPass( firstClass );
               } // end if
               else
                  System.out.println( "Next flight leaves in 3 hours." );
            } // end else if

         } // end else if

         System.out.println();

      } // end while

      System.out.println( "The plane is now full." );      

   } // end method checkIn

} // end class Airline
```

'''

Comment: You can always add the main method and test the class method by method

Comment: Rename the file `Airline.java`; **or** create a new `Airline` class in eclipse. Copy and paste this into eclipse.

Comment: It doesn't need a `main` method to compile. You can add one, or you can create your own class, instantiate an `Airline`, and call its `checkIn` method, i.e. `Airline airline = new Airline(); airline.checkIn();`

Comment: OK .. I think the prof is expecting David's technique .. thanks to everyone for the input

Comment: Thanks David .. I created my own class and called the checkIn() so I could run the program .. I have it running.  From my beginner viewpoint, the code looks good.  Not sure how I can improve on it with my limited skills.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a valid java source file, so just rename it to `Airplane.java` (public classes must always be in a source file named after itself; given that this contains `public class Airplane`, the source file must therefore be named `Airplane.java` precisely like that, and mind the casing!

It has no main method but that's no problem, you can still compile it. You simply cannot run it (trying to do `java Airline` would produce the error: `no main method found`). You can make another class that uses the `Airline` class, or, you can add a main method to the Airline class.